# Do I pay gift taxes in US, if I send money (>$15000) to my father in India?

Tags: united-states, irs, gift-tax, f1-student-visa, h-1b-visa

I am in the US on F1 visa - OPT, I need to send money to pay off my student loan in India. I have already sent about $25000 to my dad, who has paid it to the bank for my student loan and I am planning to send about $15000 more for the same purpose.

I think my dad does not owe any taxes, because in India there are no gift taxes, but I just read somewhere that in US I have to pay gift taxes for amount above $15000. I am a non-resident alien for tax purposes but that might change in October when my status will change to H1B. I am really confused here and I am not sure what to do. I want to pay off my student debt ASAP, but I also do not want to end up paying huge taxes here in US on my already taxed income.

I also read about something called a lifetime exemption on IRS gift tax, but I am not sure how does that work.

Looking forward to some suggestions.

Comment: Why do you think this should be considered a gift? This is not a gift in any way.

Comment: The lifetime exception basically says that any gift *over* the annual limit can be "charged" against the lifetime exception. It's essentially a non-issue, unless you plan on dying and leaving more than $11 million to your father.

Comment: Since you say 'parents' in the title, if it were a gift (which it isn't here), you could send $30000 in total to your mother and father in the US without any gift tax consequences.

Comment: If you want to avoid any doubt about whether this is actually just a gift to support your parents, you could just pay it to the bank directly.

Comment: There is gift tax in India as well for amount above 50k INR. IDK who pays it.

Comment: @user91988 I thought it would be considered gift because I am not paying the bank directly, and I don't know if IRS has a way of knowing what my dad is doing with the money, since he is neither a US citizen nor living in the US. IRS can only see where money goes from my account. I am not sure about this though.

Comment: @JonCuster Edited the title, I wasn't aware of the tax consequences so I sent all money to my dad's account only.

Comment: @NewBee The IRS might *think* that (idk how the IRS works, but it sounds possible). *If the IRS asks you*, "hey where did this money go, was it a gift?", then you show them the paperwork from India which says it went to the student loan, and they say "oh okay it wasn't a gift." If the paperwork doesn't match reality, it's the paperwork that is wrong, and you fix the paperwork! Wrong paperwork doesn't make a gift into a not-gift or vice versa.

Comment: Can I suggest you bypass you dad & pay of your loan directly. You can use a service like [transferwise](https://transferwise.com/gb/send-money/send-money-to-india#:~:text=TransferWise%20makes%20transferring%20money%20to,your%20debit%20or%20credit%20card.) to make a payment from one currency to another. Either to your own bank account and pay your loan from there or directly to whomever your loan is with. That way there is not even a hint of tax evasion/gifting etc. Both on your side and on your dad's side. If nothing else transferwise have good conversion rates so you are better off that way.

Comment: @NewBee It doesn't matter what the IRS thinks. It matters what you're doing with the money. You are not giving your parents this money as a gift, so it is not a gift. It's not any more complicated than that.

Comment: Is your name on the loan?

Answer (score 61):

> **What is considered a gift?**
> Any transfer to an individual, either directly or indirectly, where full consideration (measured in money or money's worth) is not received in return.

https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/frequently-asked-questions-on-gift-taxes

If you send $40,000 to your dad, and your dad pays down your student loans by $40,000, then your dad has provided value to you equal to the transfer, so it is not a gift to your dad. You are simply sending the money to your dad for him to use on your behalf. If a store hands $10,000 over to an armored car driver to take to the bank, is this a "gift"? No, the driver is simply acting as an agent of the store, just as your dad is acting as your agent. Your dad isn't the ultimate recipient, just a courier.

This also isn't a gift to the bank you owe the loan to, as $40,000 in debt is being discharged, which is consideration in return for the money.

Comment: So, do I have pay any taxes on this money in the US ? Or do I have to report this on any of the federal tax forms ?

Comment: You have to pay taxes when you *receive* the money, but not when you send it. A gift tax is really a tax paid on behalf of the *recipient*. But that recipient must owe US taxes in order for you to owe a gift tax. Suppose you gave a large gift to your dad, who is not a US citizen. He does not owe a US gift tax, and therefore, neither do you. However, he may owe taxes to India.

Comment: I think there might be a tax _reporting_ consequence, despite no actual tax consequence.  It seems to me that FBAR is probably required - even if it's nominatively dad's account, since dad is just acting as an agent on OP's behalf, it seems to me like it probably meets FBAR criteria, no?  (Though, perhaps a different question would be appropriate.)

Comment: I thought it would be considered gift because I am not paying the bank directly, and I don't know if IRS has a way of knowing what my dad is doing with the money, since he is neither a US citizen nor living in the US. IRS can only see where money goes from my account. I am not sure about this though.

Comment: @Joe Does this FBAR rule apply to me, because I am not a US citizen, so I don't think I am required to report my accounts outside the US, or am I ?

Comment: Thanks for responding everyone though, happy to know that I don't owe any taxes :D

Comment: @NewBee I believe that if you're a tax resident, then yes it would.  You may or may not be, depending on other details not present here.